# Compute minimum distance between two convex polygons in 2d

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

The points of each polygon are given in a clockwise direction. We can assume that they don't intersect. Can we calculate the distance between two convex polygons in 2D in linear or log time? A naive approach would be to enumerate all vertices and segments and compute their distance, and I would like to improve from this O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: The minimal distance between 2 convex polygons $P$, $Q$ equals to the minimal distance of origin to $P + (-Q)$, the Minkowski sum of $P$ and $-Q \stackrel{def}{=} \{ -q : q \in Q \}$. This can be computed in linear time. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition#Two_convex_polygons_in_the_plane) for a brief description of the algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.